# Loadrunner _ running multiple users back to back, calculating file download time and right approach for debugging 500 internal server error

Tags: loadrunner

I’ve been facing a following issues with loadrunner:
1.  How to run a scenario multiple times (more than one iterations) to get more accurate results. As of now multiple users can be run but don’t have option to run them back to back.
2.  If there are some files to be downloaded from sever, it records the response time but not the time that includes downloading also. We want to get downloading time as well.
3.  500 Internal server errors are very hard to debug. We’re doing it by hit and trial as of now, look at the http request and see if there’s anything missing/extra/wrong in the functions like web_submit_data etc.

We’ve browsed on internet but didn’t find any solutions for these. As these are very general things a user could expect from LoadRunner, finding solution for these will be of great help for many users.

Please tell me if there's anything that need more details or is ambiguous. Any response is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Test101.  See your initial conditions & your in-test conditions related to shared resources.   Generally takes a controlled environment.  If you are in a virtual machine with arbitrated resources and uncontrolled initial conditions (including same data state for data sources and in test data) then you will have issues in repeatability.   Exact repeatability is not possible because of network conditions in play between generator and application under test (unless you are on the same isolated segment next to one another) but you should be able to achieve a less than 5% overall variation with controlled conditions
2. If the file is in the HTTP stream then the time to download is recorded.  Check one run with the full logs enabled for that particular request.
3. 500 generally means the following: You are not checking for expected return conditions ( Test 101, for each step there is an expected result) and when the expected conditions do not occur you are not explicitly branching your code to handle the condition.  You are likely just accepting an HTTP 200, without regard to content and moving along.  Then a couple of pages later you get a 500